# How to implement composite pattern in modern C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I had a situation that needs composite pattern as data structure. Even though I'm familiar with the composite pattern and am keen to use modern C++ to implement the composite pattern, I'm having trouble with things like memory management. I would have liked to use C++ references to make it safer, and I didn't want to use wild pointers (as this increases the risk of memory errors), nor did I want to use `std::shared_ptr` (because this thing is so poor that using it a lot will take up a lot of unnecessary extra memory). So I tried using C++ references and made up code like this:

```cpp
import <vector>;
import <iostream>;
import <string>;
import <memory>;
import <stdexcept>;
import <initializer_list>;

// fdcl.
class Composite;

class Base
{
    public:
        Base() = delete;
        Base(Base const&) = delete;
        Base(Base&&) = default;
        
        Base& operator=(Base const&) = delete;
        Base& operator=(Base&&) = default;

        virtual ~Base() = default;


        virtual Composite &composite();
        virtual Composite const& composite() const;

        virtual void someAction() = 0;
};

Composite &Base::composite()
{
    throw std::logic_error("Base::composite() called");
}

Composite const& Base::composite() const
{
    throw std::logic_error("Base::composite() const called");
}

class A final : public Base
{
    public:
        A() = default;
        A(A const&) = default;
        A(A&&) = default;
        A& operator=(A const&) = default;
        A& operator=(A&&) = default;
        ~A() = default;

        virtual void someAction() override;
};

void A::someAction()
{
    std::cout << "A::someAction() called" << std::endl;
}




class Composite final : public Base
{
    public:
        Composite() = default;
        Composite(Composite const&);
        Composite(Composite&&) = default;
        Composite& operator=(Composite const&);
        Composite& operator=(Composite&&) = default;
        ~Composite() = default;

        /* I want to use copy-swap here. but how to copy these `std::unique_ptr`s,
         using `std::make_unique`? or using `new` in the call of constructor with
         type casts? */

        void swap(Composite &other);

        Composite(std::initializer_list<Base &>);

        virtual void someAction() override;
        virtual Composite &composite() override;
        virtual Composite const& composite() const override;

        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> &data();
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> const& data() const;
    private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> childrens;
};

Composite &Composite::operator=(Composite const& other)
{
    Composite copy {other};
    /* how to implement the copy constructor? */
    swap(copy);
    return *this;
}

Composite::Composite(Composite const& other)
{
    /* how to implement this? */
}

Composite::Composite(std::initializer_list<Base &> initial)
{
    for (auto& element : initial)
    {
        childrens.push_back(
            /* I want to put a `std::make_unique<>()` here, but how can I convert them, 
            and **create correct types copying them *separately***?    */);
    }
}

Composite &Composite::composite() { return *this; }
Composite const& Composite::composite() const { return *this; }

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> &Composite::data() { return childrens; }
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> const& Composite::data() const { return childrens; }

void Composite::someAction()
{
    std::cout << "Composite::someAction() called" << std::endl;
}
```

I started out using `std::initializer_list<Base &>` as arguments to the constructor, copying data from the constructor to `std::unique_ptr` objects as members of the `children` variable inside the `Composite` class. Then I had trouble implementing the "copy swap" idiomatic semantics in the `Composite` because I couldn't implement the copy constructor correctly (because I couldn't create instances of the correct type)

Comment: In a polymorphic class hierarchy one should usually disallow any copying (delete the copy constructor and copy assignment).

Comment: Or start adding `clone()` functions to each derived class. Or wrap `unique_ptr` in your own class to make it copyable (store a function pointer to a lambda that does the copy).